# libtool in cross-compile: relinking issue only on arm target; i386/x86_64/aarch64 targets are OK

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I adding to my project (MiniMyth2) additional targets: arm and aarch64 
(MiniMyth2 uses cross-compile to build mythtv appliance for given platform).

I have nicely cross-compiling (and working appliance) for: i386, x86_64 and aarch64.

All targets are built with exactly the same packages, build system, makefiles, etc. To select target I'm changing only: cross-compilation target string and gcc/ld flags.

This works Ok for i386, x86_64 and aarch64 - but not for ARM target.

On ARM however I have many packages failing with libtool relinking. Usually failure looks like this:

```
make[11]: Entering directory `/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/gtk/glib/work/main.d/glib-2.53.1/gmodule'
 //home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/bin/mkdir -p '/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib'
 //home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install //home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/bin/install -c   libgmodule-2.0.la '/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib'
libtool: warning: relinking 'libgmodule-2.0.la'
libtool: install: (cd /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/gtk/glib/work/main.d/glib-2.53.1/gmodule; //home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/bin/bash "/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/gtk/glib/work/main.d/glib-2.53.1/libtool"  --tag CC --mode=relink armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -pipe -march=armv7-a -O2 -flto -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,nodelete -Wl,--export-dynamic -version-info 5301:0:5301 -export-dynamic -Wl,--as-needed -pipe -pipe -march=armv7-a -O2 -flto -o libgmodule-2.0.la -rpath /usr/lib libgmodule_2_0_la-gmodule.lo -ldl ../glib/libglib-2.0.la -inst-prefix-dir /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main)
libtool: relink: armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libgmodule_2_0_la-gmodule.o   -ldl -L/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/main/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -lglib-2.0 -lpcre -lpthread  -march=armv7-a -O2 -flto -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z -Wl,nodelete -Wl,--export-dynamic -Wl,--as-needed -march=armv7-a -O2 -flto   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -o .libs/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.5301.0
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool:   error: error: relink 'libgmodule-2.0.la' with the above command before installing it
make[11]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
```

Of course /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so will be not recognised as it is for x86_64 architecture (my OS on which I'm cross-compiling is x86_64) while target is ARM.

But:
**Why libtool relinking is looking for /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so durring durring relinking on ARM target - but not on i386, x86_64 and aarch64 targets?**

Only difference between targets in my cross-building process are: target string and gcc/ld flags:

```
NAME:        cross-compilation target (in glibc, etc):
c3           -> i586-minimyth-linux-gnu
c3-2         -> i586-minimyth-linux-gnu
pentium-mmx  -> i586-minimyth-linux-gnu
atom         -> x86_64-minimyth-linux-gnu
x86-64       -> x86_64-minimyth-linux-gnu
armv7        -> armv7a-minimyth-linux-gnueabihf
armv8        -> aarch64-minimyth-linux-gnu
```

gcc/ld lfags:

```
c3           -> -march=atom -mtune=atom -O2 -mfpmath=sse -ftree-vectorize -mmovbe
c3-2         -> -march=c3-2 -mtune=c3-2 -Os -mfpmath=sse
pentium-mmx  -> -march=pentium-mmx -mtune=generic  -Os
atom         -> -march=atom -mtune=atom -O2 -mfpmath=sse -ftree-vectorize -mmovbe
x86-64       -> -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic  -O3 -mfpmath=sse
armv7        -> -march=armv7-a -O2
armv8        -> -march=armv8-a -O2
```

and gcc common for all: `-pipe -flto`

ld common for all: `-Wl,--as-needed -pipe -flto`

Rest (packages, makefiles, etc are exactly the same)

gcc is 7.3.0, glibc is 2.27, binutils are 2.28.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like issue in this question is well known issue of libtool in cross-compile enviroment.

Guys from Yocto project seems to address many libtool cross-compile problems.

Following patches from Yocto project allows me to cross-compile my whole project to all 4 targets (arm, aarch64, i386 and x86_64):

[libtool-2.4.6-fixinstall.patch](https://github.com/warpme/minimyth2/blob/master/script/devel/libtool/files/libtool-2.4.6-fixinstall.patch)

[libtool-2.4.6-trailingslash.patch](https://github.com/warpme/minimyth2/blob/master/script/devel/libtool/files/libtool-2.4.6-trailingslash.patch)